# nuget command to IncludeReferencedProjects in azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, nuget

In Azure devops I want to issue a nuget pack command that passes the option `IncludeReferencedProjects`.  My repo is in TFVC so I do not believe I can use azure-pipelines.yml.  I believe I must do this through the visual designer.  I don't see an option to pass additional arguments to the nuget with the pack command type.  This makes me think I have to use the custom command type for nuget.  When I'm using the custom command type, I can specify -IncludeReferencedProjects but I do not seem to be able to specify **\*.csproj as the items to pack.  If I do this the command fails with:

```
[command]C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\NuGet\4.1.0\x64\nuget.exe pack **\*.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects -Symbols -Verbosity Detailed -NonInteractive
System.IO.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

How can I pack all csproj output with the `IncludeReferencedProjects` flag using the visual designer?  Here's a picture of what I have in designer:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> How can I pack all csproj output with the IncludeReferencedProjects flag using the visual designer?

I am afraid you could not pack **all** csproj output with the IncludeReferencedProjects flag.

That because [pack command (NuGet CLI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-pack) **does not support wildcard**.

When you use nuget pack command line with wildcard, you will always get the error `Unknown command: '**\*.csproj'`. (This error also exists locally.)

To resolve this issue, we could add multiple nuget pack tasks to pack those projects.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like the devops visual designer is doing some magic for me when I use a nuget task with a command type of 'pack', as there I can specify **\\*.csproj and it works.  It just doesn't give me the option to pass IncludeReferencedProjects.  When I switch my nuget task to a command type of 'custom' I lose all the devops magic and that's why wildcards do not work.

Comment: this is really inconvenient. Pack should support extra option or custom should support path with wildcard

Answer (score 0):

For me, passing `IncludeReferencedProjects=true` worked.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Pack Core.Shared
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    versioningScheme: 'byPrereleaseNumber'
    majorVersion: '1'
    minorVersion: '0'
    patchVersion: '0'
    buildProperties: 'IncludeReferencedProjects=true'
```

Comment: Sadly this didn't work for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me either. I read posts about the different workarounds, I decided it's not worth it and simply added a pipeline to publish the other project as an internal nuget package for our Azure DevOps team and used it it.